# Why is this general switch between short exact sequences well defined/allowed?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In a larger proof, the author used this transformation between short exact sequences, which seems as though it might be useful in general.
$\require{AMScd}$

\begin{CD}
0 @>>> M' @>\alpha>> M @>\beta >> M'' @>>> 0\\
@. @V{\alpha}V\sim V @V{\operatorname{id}}V\sim V @V{\gamma}V\sim V \\
0 @>>>\alpha(M')@>>>M@>>>M/\alpha(M')@>>>0
\end{CD}

The author claims that all vertical arrows are in fact isomorphism. The first two are clear. For the last one $(\gamma)$, take $x\in M''$, then by surjectivity of $\beta$ there is $y\in M$ with $\beta(y)=x$. Now define $\gamma(x) := \bar y\in M/\alpha(M')$ which is "well defined, as the rows are exact".

I don't see why this is the case. In particular, as $\beta$ is only surjective, there may be another $y'$ which also maps to $x$. How can we be sure that $\bar y=\bar y'\in M/\alpha(M')$? Couldn't $y\in \alpha(M')$ and $y'\not\in\alpha(M')$ hold, since $\alpha$ is only injective?

Comment: You can do this either by universal property of quotients, or by the five (or four) lemma.  Take your pick.

Comment: @user10354138 How can we apply the universal property, I've only ever used it for existence (not defined-ness)? I don't know the other lemmas you reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Couldn't $y\in \alpha(M')$ and $y'\not\in\alpha(M')$ hold, since $\alpha$ is only injective?

No, that cannot hold, precisely because the rows are exact.

In fact, we have $$\beta(y-y')=\beta(y)-\beta(y')=x-x=0$$which by exactness implies $y-y'\in \alpha(M')$. This, by definition of quotient, means that $\overline y=\overline{y'}$, making $\gamma(x)$ well-defined.